# Unable to scroll collapsing toolbar with recyclerview using fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

i am using NavigationView and BottomMenu both in single activity. Using fragment on clicking of bottom menu i am using Collapsing Toolbar and Recyclerview. When i scroll recyclerview only recyclerview scroll but collapsing toolbar is not collapsed. Here is my code. Please help me.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#F1F1F1"
android:focusable="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:id="@+id/vp_new_banner"/>

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/vp_indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                app:centered="true"
                app:fillColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:pageColor="#ffffff"
                app:snap="false" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/new_data_2" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the xml code of where the RecyclerView is? My guess is you didn't include `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` for the RecyclerView.

Comment: I can share xml code, but i want to clear here i already used app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" for RecyclerView